# Call a smart contract function with web3py using private key

Tags: web3.py, smart-contract-wallets, private-key

I'm trying to call a smart contract function using web3py; the idea is to mint a token using a wallets private key. I've done it before in web3.js but I'm not sure how to move forward with web3py.

I'm not sure about the `txdict` variable; what will be the value of `data`?

```
{
  to: ''
  data: ''
  gas: ''
  gasPrice: ''
}
```

Suggestions will be appreciated!

```
from web3 import Web3
infura_url = '...'
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
abi = '...'
address = '...'
privateKey = '...'
contract_instance = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)

payload = [
    [
        5,  # Add editions count
        '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',  # Add creators address
        '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        0,
        '',  # Add metadata url
        5,  # Add editions count
    ],
]

tx_hash = contract_instance.functions.oboCreateManyMediasAndReleases(
    payload).transact()

tx_dict = '??'
signed = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx_dict, privateKey)
txid = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction).hex()
```

Answer (score 0):

- [Import your private key as an environment variable to web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#read-a-private-key-from-an-environment-variable).
- [To call smart contract function you need to import its ABI file](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#interacting-with-existing-contracts). Then you can call the contract using a Python proxy class.